# StatusIcon not showing/working

Tags: icons, development, gtk, vala

Good morning dear community, i have a little trouble and i can't found any proper explanation for this issue, actually i'm developing an small application to hear radio streaming using Vala and Granite, the problem comes when i try to make a **StatusIcon** for the app, i followed the related documentation in various site but no one works i'm doing something bad?

this is my code:

```
trayicon = new StatusIcon.from_icon_name("gtk-home");
        trayicon.set_tooltip_text("Tray");
        trayicon.set_visible(true);
        trayicon.set_has_tooltip(true);
```

according with the documentation that might work but doesn't.

let me know if you guys need to the the full code.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GtkStatusIcon is deprecated since GTK 3.14. It is more for Windows and KDE and not supported on elementary OS or Gnome 3.

Comment: ok, then i can't put functionality to my app? or is there another way to get it, thank you for clear it.

Comment: What functionality do you want? I suppose you want to switch stations while not showing the window. This will be best in the Quicklist menu in plank. For this you can use libunity. See for a example here http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon/switchboard/switchboard/view/head:/src/Switchboard.vala#L239

Comment: i mean put my app icon here http://i.douglasbrunal.co/26-10-16-NUTsnumB.png

Comment: I now what you mean. My question is why you want it there?

Comment: cause if an user want to stop the streaming can click in the icon to display a menu where will find settings, play, stop and exit the app does not have a visible gui.

Comment: Yeah. So that would be best suited in quicklist as mentioned above. So you get a icon in plank with those actions.

Comment: I would not recommend it but if you still want it as indicator you can look at AppIndicators https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators

Comment: ok, both answers are valid please mark as solved, thank you so much you've been very helpfull

Comment: Anytime. Only you can mark it as solved.